# Using calc() for height of jQuery-ui dialog to set it based on window height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a jQueryUI dialog be the height and width of the *window* (minus some padding). Ideally I'd set these options to be like CSS values of `calc(100% - 100px)` **instead of grabbing `$(window).height()` and then having to deal with updating things should the user resize the window**.

This is working for `width` but not `height`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<button>Open Dialog</button>
<div id="filters-dialog" style="display: none;">
  asdf<br/>
  asdf<br/>
  asdf<br/>
  asdf<br/>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("#filters-dialog").dialog().dialog("open");
})
$("#filters-dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  width: "calc(100% - 100px)",
  height: "calc(100% - 100px)",
});
```

A few things I have tried to get this working include setting the `minHeight` option, setting `height` and `minHeight` as dialog options upon `open:` or `create:`, trying to override `.ui-dialog`'s CSS of `height` or `min-height` or `top`upon `open:` or `create:` (setting CSS this way seems to work for certain properties but not these), setting the CSS of body and html to `height: 100%`, and throwing around `!important`.

Here is **[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yynpu1ow/)** with my attempts commented out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI's Dialog widget only accepts height as a `Number` or `"auto"`, passing it `"calc(100% - 100px)"` will just default it to `"auto"`. Its min/maxHeight are Number only. You'll have to do this programmatically after the dialog has opened. Keep in mind that when you call the `.dialog()` property, you're selecting the content inside the dialog, not the wrapping div of the dialog, so to set the actual height of the window, you'll need to select the parent of the `.dialog()`:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("#filters-dialog").dialog().dialog("open");
});

$("#filters-dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  width: "calc(100% - 100px)",
  open: function() {
    $(this).parent().css("height", "calc(100% - 100px)");
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that if you do this, the content section won't resize properly as-is, so if your content is larger than window, it'll look weird.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the content in my case will inevitably be longer than the window. I suppose one way to handle that programmatically would be to set the content box's height to something like `"calc(100% - " + adjustment + "px)"` where `adjustment` = dialog title bar height + dialog button pane height (left out of my example) + dialog padding + dialog border. Blech, feels dirty, but I think it would work.

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg posted an answer that might help.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height are set on the widget via style attribute. For example:

```
<div style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 404px; top: 50px; left: 45.8px; z-index: 101;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" aria-describedby="filters-dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
```

The width is set here and height is `auto`. The height is then calculated for the content, not the entire dialog div:

```
<div id="filters-dialog" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 201.6px;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
```

This is all set as part of the wrapping and can be accessed via `widget` option. To adjust this, you can't use CSS, since the style attribute on the elements will be in control. (Can try setting `""` as the value, but I don't think it will drop it all together.)

Adjusting the width should be pretty direct. Adjusting the height, not so much. The height is not just `100% - 100px`, it is `(100% - 100px) - .ui-dialog-content padding - .ui-dialog-titlebar height (with padding) - .ui-dialog padding`. Not impossible, just complex.

At this point, personally, I would use the window height and width and be done with it. How often do you anticipate the user resizing the window?

So how to go forward. Can try something like this:

```
open: function() {
  $(this).dialog("widget").css("width", "calc(100% - 100px)");
  $(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("height", "calc(100% - 100px)");
}
```

It's not pretty, yet it does what is needed. Working: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4cjm2ood/

I don't know that this will have the intended result. The `100%` height is going to be bound to the parent and thus calculate the wrong height. You might be better off to strip the style and let your CSS do the work.

The first thing to remember is that we need to selectively remove certain styling, not just wiping it all out.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4cjm2ood/2/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function removeStyleAttr(list, item) {
    var parts = list.split(";");
    parts = parts.slice(0, -1);
    var styles = {},
      newList = "";
    $.each(parts, function(i, s) {
      var k = s.split(":")[0].trim();
      var v = s.split(":")[1].trim();
      styles[k] = v;
    });
    if (typeof item != "string") {
      $.each(item, function(k, v) {
        delete styles[v];
      });
    } else {
      delete styles[item];
    }
    $.each(styles, function(key, val) {
      newList += key + ": " + val + "; "
    });
    return newList.slice(0, -1);
  }

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#filters-dialog").dialog("open");
  });

  $("#filters-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    classes: {
      "ui-dialog": "ui-diag-top",
      "ui-dialog-content": "ui-diag-content"
    },
    modal: true,
    width: $(window).width() - 100,
    height: $(window).height() - 100,
    open: function() {
      var s1 = $(this).dialog("widget").attr("style");
      var s2 = removeStyleAttr(s1, ["width", "height"]);
      var s3 = $(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-content").attr("style");
      var s4 = removeStyleAttr(s3, "height");
      $(this).dialog("widget").attr("style", s2);
      $(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-content").attr("style", s4);
    }
  });
});
```

First a small function: `removeStyleAttr(List, Item)`

- List (String) - A listing of all the CSS style assigned to an element
- Item (String, Array) - The Specific Style(s) we want to remove
- Return Value is a new string of all the remaining CSS styles.

So now we have a way to slice out one specific style from a element, for example "width". Once those are removed, we can use our own CSS. To do that, I advise using `classes` to add your own class names.

Using `open` callback, we strip off the `width` and `height` of the wrapper, and `height` of the content. This returns the control to our CSS.

**CSS**

```
.ui-diag-top {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.ui-diag-content {
  height: auto;
}
```

The wrapper gets to be the right size, the toolbar remains the same, and the content will be `auto` to fill in the rest.

Now if you think you'd have to do this a lot, you might consider the Widget Factory and build a Super Dialog that allows you to accept a String value versus an Integer for width and height.

**Update 1**

The `width` option will accept `calc(100% - 100px)` without issues. `height` is operated on and needs some override.

**Update 2**

While `width` and `height` are stores as the value `calc(100% - 100px)`, there are resize functions that compare against these values:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/dialog.js

> Line 788: `if ( options.minWidth > options.width ) {`
>
> Line 789:   `options.width = options.minWidth;`
>
> Line 790: `}`

Even thought you can, you risk breaking some things. I would just make a function that can be called during resize events that adjusts the `width` and `height`.

**Update 3**

Here is a much cleaner solution that allows for resizing and does not rely on CSS.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4cjm2ood/6/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.superDialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    options: {
      useWindowOffset: false,
      windowOffset: 0
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
      if (this.options.useWindowOffset) {
        this.applyWindowOffset();
      }
      this._super(event);
    },
    _resetWidth: function(ow, dw) {
      var nw = $(ow).width() - dw;
      this._setOption("width", nw);
    },
    _resetHeight: function(ow, dh) {
      var nh = $(ow).height() - dh;
      this._setOption("height", nh);
    },
    applyWindowOffset: function() {
      var o = this.options.windowOffset;
      if (typeof o == "object" && o.length > 1) {
        this._resetWidth(this.window, o[0]);
        this._resetHeight(this.window, o[1]);
      }
      if (typeof o == "number") {
        this._resetWidth(this.window, o);
        this._resetHeight(this.window, o);
      }
      console.log(this.options);
    },
    resizeWindowOffset: function(event) {
      this.applyWindowOffset();
      this._size();
    }
  });

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#filters-dialog").superDialog("open");
  });

  $("#filters-dialog").superDialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "I am offset!",
    useWindowOffset: true,
    windowOffset: 100
  });

  $(window).resize(function(e) {
    $("#filters-dialog").superDialog("resizeWindowOffset", e);
  })
});
```

Making use of the Widget Factory, we can create our own custom dialog widget. We add a few options and methods so we can make use of a size based on an offset of the window.

- `useWindowOffset`: Boolean, default `false`
- `windowOffset`: Integer or Array, default `0`. Set `useWindowOffset` to true and set an offset value in pixels or an array (`[width, height]`) in pixels.
- `applyWindowOffset()`: This does not accept any arguements. Apply the new Width and Height values to dialog. Executed before `open`.
- `resizeWindowOffset()`: This accepts `event` yet does not use it at this time. Call when window is resized to apply changes in size.

No more updates on this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your many options and explanations. I feel kind of terrible that you've so generally offered up so much work that I may not be able to use. Maybe I should have specified in the question to not bother getting too complex. :-) Was expecting there might be a rather painless solution I was missing that could easily incorporate calc() for height. But I learned quite a bit from your code.

Comment: _"How often do you anticipate the user resizing the window?"_ For better or worse, it's probably more likely that important stakeholders will be adjusting their windows when testing my work's responsiveness. _"I would just make a function that can be called during resize events that adjusts the width and height."_ That's what I have done for now. It was more painless than I expected it to be. But I will doubtless come back to your code when that somehow fails in a case I didn't anticipate. Thank you again!